# Render ChoiceField with radio buttons

Tags: django, django-forms

I've constructed this form from a model.

```
class Configure_template(forms.Form):
    subject_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Subject_type.objects.all())
```

And I want to render this using radio buttons but I have problems with the for in the html,

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 14):

Use a [`RadioSelect` widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.RadioSelect) on your form field:

```
subject_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Subject_type.objects.all(),
    widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

Comment: thanks, I've just added that now, but can you tell me how to construct the html {% for choice in form.action_type.field.choices %}
       <li>
         <input type="radio" name="action_type" value="{{choice.0}}"
           {% ifequal form.action_type.data choice.0 %}
             checked="checked"
           {% endifequal %}/>
         <label for="">{{choice.1}}</label>

Comment: after to render i got an error                                                'Subject_type' object does not support indexing

Comment: Why don't you just let django render the entire form with `{{ form.as_p }}`?

Comment: Actually, I am really confused, I have to many information but what I want to do is to create a view where a user can select one option in each of the 5 fields through radio buttons and then a second user can  have another view where another form will show up according the fields that the first user has selected. Can you give me some suggestion?

Comment: What I have is one service that have 5 fields and the user has to enter and select options of this fields (Configuration of the template). After this form been summited, a second user will enter and will have another form  but just according the configuration did by the first user in what I call template.

Comment: I could render the html but with manual choices before the form subject_choices= (
 ('0', 'Identity'), ('1', 'Deparment'),)
resource_choices= (
('0', 'Identity'), ('1', 'Deparment'),)
action_choices= (
('0', 'Read'), ('1', 'Modify'), ('2', 'Delete') ) but now I put these choices in the database

Answer (score 4):

If you want to show radiobuttons with choices from database use cannot use ChoiceField.

You have to use a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField).

```
subject_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, queryset=Subject_type.objects.all(), label='')
```