# Update database field with multiple buttons

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a small project using Django and I have a detail page of a digital product. The user should have the avability to update the status of this product through 3 Buttons. This status represents one ChoiceField in the database. The choices are: Dismiss, In Review and Approve.
Clicking the button should submit the form directly.

[image]

My question is, what is the best way to solve that (without Ajax)?

My first idea was to add 3 forms and every form has another action url.

I'm still fairly new to Django and don't know if my approach is the best solution.

Comment: what about to make `links` look like a `buttons` and just pass some info in the query to the `view`, and make view react differently on the parameters it get? if u wanna i can make some code for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347040/render-choicefield-with-radio-buttons) and in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect) you should be able to get what you want with a `RadioSelect` form widget.

If you add a bit of CSS to hide the radio inputs themselves, and style the labels as buttons, you should be good!

Edit to include my comment below:
To get a single click submission, you could write some simple javascript that catches the `onclick` event on your buttons, and submits the form as you click.

Comment: That requires an extra submit button. The user should only click once without having to make a selection.

Comment: I see. Without AJAX, I can't think of another way than the 3 forms you mention in your question. Unless you're ok with some javascript, in which case you could probably capture the `onClick` on the buttons, and submit the form from the code. It feels a bit hacky though.

Comment: I think thats a great idea. I can use the radio buttons and submit it with jQuery when one is selected. I will try this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could I ask for your opinion one more time? I just found another way to do this without JS. I can add multiple submit buttons with a different value `<button type="submit" name="status" value="approve">Approve</button> ...` What do you think about this?

Comment: If it works, I'd go for that latest idea, if you don't use javascript, you're avoiding potential compatibility problems with certain browsers, and also making it work for users who turn off javascript. In the end, it probably depends on your specific applications/users, but it does seem like a good idea. Plus all your code is in the same place (ie: the python form, as opposed to split between templates and forms), so better maintainability.